# How to append --EOF to CSV file after transforming JSON to CSV in Mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I want to append --EOF at the end of file in CSV after transforming JSON to CSV in Mule Data Weave 2.0

### Input:

{
"serialNumber": "ABCD",
"asset": "EFGH" }

### Output:

ABCD|EFGH

--EOF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the write() function to write the output as a string so you can concatenate it to the EOF string that you want.

Example:

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
write(payload, "application/csv", {"header":false, "separator" : "|"}) ++ "\n--EOF"
```

Comment: Thanks!! It's Working.